# What do these money-related gestures mean?

Tags: numbers, counting, non-verbal-communication

The following images come from the Korean manhwa *Aura From Another Planet*, chapter 35. I can guess that the gestures they are making refer to monetary amounts, but how much are we talking here?

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: The first one is common across East Asia and just means "money". It is roughly equivalent to the American gesture where you rub your thumb and index finger against each other. The second and third ones I don't recognize; they might be uniquely Korean. Perhaps chisanbop?

Comment: Yeah, I know the first one just means money-- question was directed towards the other two

Comment: Could be chisanbop, but then it would seem the two signs are equivalent?

Comment: That's not something we use in ordinary life.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the comments said, the first one means generic "money" (she's making the shape of a coin with her thumb and index finger.)

The other two, I have no idea, but considering that the comics was full of absurdist humor, I think the author just made up some nonsense gestures.  (These two girls are aliens, after all, if I remember correctly.)

Comment: So nothing to do with [지산법](https://ko.wikipedia.org/wiki/%EC%A7%80%EC%82%B0%EB%B2%95)?

Comment: Well, I don't know 지산법, so I can't be sure, but the possibility is: (1) the comics' author made up gestures for two alien girls, where exact value is not important (indeed, I think "the reader has no idea what they're talking about" is part of the joke), or (2) the author is a master of an obscure finger-based counting method, and wants to show it off as an "easter egg".  I think (1) is much more likely.